# Null pointer exception on .iterator() call

Tags: java

I'm getting a strange NullPointerException, evidently thrown by the following line of code:

```
Iterator<Note> it = notes.iterator();
```

I've checked, and at the time the java.util.TreeSet `notes` is always non-null (with 15 elements). The TreeSet API says nothing about `iterator()` throwing NullPointerExceptions. What else could be going here?

Comment: Can you post the code where you populate the tree and where you're instantiating notes?

Comment: Can we see the stack trace? Are you 100% sure the NPE was thrown at this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `notes` is not `null` then:

- You are mistaken (never discount this option).
- The implementation of `notes` is broken.
- You are using the implementation incorrectly - for instance having multiple threads access it at once.

Comment: If the NPE came from the line he says, then (1) is the only explanation that I can see. The other two options would cause the NPE elsewhere.